# Rank theorem rudin

Tags: analysis, derivatives, linear-transformations, matrix-rank, inverse-function

There are the theorem and it's proof:
My question is below.
[image]

[image]

[image]
I don't understand How the last formula shows that $\varphi$ $\in$ $\mathscr C'$. in $\mathscr C'$ we mean continuously differentiable functions.

Comment: I haven't read in detail, but under $(72)$, it is concluded that $\psi$ is $\mathscr{C}'$. Since $S$ is a linear map between finite-dimensional spaces, it will also be continuous and differentiable. Thus, $(80)$ makes $\varphi$ a composition of continuously differentiable functions, which is continuously differentiable.

Comment: @TheoBendit then why it's implied that $y_0$ was chosen arbitrarily in $A(V)$? I don't get this line

Comment: I should probably read the proof in detail at this point, but $(80)$ specifies that the formula holds for $y \in W$, so this composition argument only works for points in $W$. But, $W$ is defined as a neighbourhood, in $A(V)$, of an arbitrary point $y_0 \in A(V)$. This isn't all of $A(V)$ necessarily, but it does show continuous differentiability at $y_0$. This same argument applies to any given $y_0 \in A(V)$, since it was chosen arbitrarily.

Comment: @TheoBendit thank you man